# How to I use the unit \erg with the siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx

I tried:

```
  \DeclareSIUnit\CoolR{\erg \centi \metre \cube \per \second}
```

I am getting an error:

```
 Undefined control sequence
 <argument> \erg
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Next time I will. The first answer worked for me so I have accepted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

erg is not an unit from the SI, so it's not in the `siunitx` package.

You can declare it the same way you're declaring `\coolR`:

```
\DeclareSIUnit\erg{erg}
```

then:

```
\DeclareSIUnit\CoolR{\erg \centi \metre \cubed \per \second}
```

---

Also, it's `\cubed`, not `\cube`.